# Image looks GOOD on the editor but BAD (blurry) on the HTML5 export

Tags: unity, 2d, gui, html5

I have a red bar that looks good inside Unity editor, but when I export the build it looks very strange.
Any idea on how to fix this?

[image: Side-by-side comparison]

The image on the left is the one with the strange/bad looking red bar...

[image: The Editor info]

Comment: Under aniso level on the import settings there is platform specific compression. You should check the settings for html 5.